# Determine if $\{ \emptyset, \{1\},\{2,3\},\{1,4\},\{2,3,4\},\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,3,4\} \}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I have the following set:
$$M=\{ \emptyset, \{1\},\{2,3\},\{1,4\},\{2,3,4\},\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,3,4\}     \}$$

and I want determine if this is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\{1,2,3,4\}.$

I could try all combinations but that seems a bit ineffective. Another idea I was thinking, is to show that I can produce $\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\}$ from M but I cannot find any proof that this actually would result in a $\sigma$-algebra.

Any help/hint would be appreciated.

Comment: The intersection of two elements in a sigma-algebra must be in that sigma-algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{1,4\}\setminus \{1\}$ is not in this class, so it is not  a sigma algebra.